# Possible changes highlighting/rendering bug in Edit Review page

Tags: bug, editing, suggested-edits

So, this is an edit I just got approved a few minutes ago: https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/73579

I see a very minor discrepancy that may still be a bug though.

First, the markdown side-by-side:

[image: markdown]

As you can see, I add some code formatting around "Cc:" and "Subject:" to make it more reminiscent of the terminal output being seen.  The "and a" portion between them is untouched.

Here's where the bug is - in the rendered content:

[image: rendered]

Rendered, it says the "and" was removed and added.  While this is a minor issue and I might just be anal about bugs and wanting to be a perfectionist at times, is this something that can be fixed?  Or is it just on my end.

Comment: This regularly happens with edits. I don't remember why but I assume it is known and just not worth "fixing". Don't remember where my source was though.